# Como puedo mandar la sumatoria de mi array a php

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo una función que llena mi *array* y lo manda a la función `suma()` para sacar la sumatoria; después mando un *array* de tipo *JSON* a mi archivo de *PHP* y lo recibo correctamente y lo inserto.

Lo que quiero ahora es guardar la suma de ese *array* e insertarlo, pero cuando lo quiero recibir en mi archivo *PHP* me sale *null*. Pensé que no lo estaba convirtiendo correctamente pero al hacer un `console.log(JSON.stringify(sumaT))` y, también haciendo un `console.log(jsonsuma)`, sí me da la suma del *array*, pero en *PHP* me sale *null*.

```
const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#añadir');
const inputAgregarVar = document.querySelector('#inputventa');


var arrayinput = [];
let sumaT = 0;

function listado() {
if (inputAgregarVar.value == '') {
    vacio();
    inputventa.focus();
} else if (inputAgregarVar.value > 0) {
    arrayinput.push(parseFloat(inputAgregarVar.value));
    inputAgregarVar.value = '';
    inputAgregarVar.focus();
    mostrar(arrayinput);
    sumar(arrayinput);
} else
    Positivo();
inputventa.focus();
};

function mostrar(arrayinput) {
var listaUlVar = document.querySelector('#lista');
listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';
for (i of arrayinput) {
    var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
    listaUlVar.appendChild(listaLi);
    listaLi.innerText = i;
    console.log(i);
}
}

   function sumar() {
   var listaT = document.querySelector('#listaT');
listaT.innerHTML = '';
let suma = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
    suma += arrayinput[i];
   }
var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
listaT.appendChild(listaLi);
listaLi.innerText = suma;
console.log("suma total", suma);
sumaT = suma;
}

function validacionG() {
validacion = arrayinput;
if (validacion == 0) {
    vacio();
} else

guardar();
validacion = null;
}

function guardar() {
var lista = { "data": arrayinput };
var json = JSON.stringify(lista);
ajax("procesos/Procesoventa.php", { "array": json })
    .done(function(info) {
        console.log(info);
    });
}

  function guardarSuma() {
  ajaxs("procesos/Procesoventa.php", { "suma": sumaT })
    .done(function(info) {
        console.log(info);
    });
   }
 //ajax
  function ajax(url, data) {
  var ajax = $.ajax({
    "method": "POST",
    "url": url,
    "data": data,
    success: function(resp) {
        alertaGood();
    }
   })
  return ajax;
   }

  function ajaxs(url, data) {
  var ajax = $.ajax({
    "method": "POST",
    "url": url,
    "data": data,
    success: function(resp) {
        alertaGood();
    }
   })
  return ajaxs;
   }
```

Acá recibo el *array* y la suma, el *array* lo muestra bien pero la suma no. Todavía no inserto la suma hasta que me muestre.

```
   $array = json_decode($_POST['array'], true);
    $suma = json_decode($_POST['suma']);
    var_dump($array);
    var_dump($suma);
```

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/388570/edit) para agregar el código con el que intentas recibir la suma en _PHP_, porque si con `console.log()` ves el resultado correcto en el navegador, lo más seguro es que el problema no está en Javascript, sino en _PHP_

Comment: Aunque, ahora que lo veo más detenidamente, tienes las variables `sumaT` y `jsonsuma`, donde haces procesos innecesarios, porque bastaría con ejecutar la petición con: `ajax("procesos/Procesototal.php", { "suma": suma })`, sin tener que realizar modificaciones.

Comment: intente anteriormente hacerlo así pero era lo mismo así que me base como hice cuando mande mi array de tipo json a php a eso me base

Comment: ya lo agregue..

Comment: Fíjate en network, si se envía la data correctamente @Bryan. Y ese `sumaT` no veo que esta definida en una parte de javascript

Comment: Hola @Bryan! podes explicarme de donde sale ```sumaT``` ? osea donde tenes declarado esa variable. Y la parte de la validacion creo que se puede mejorar un poco. Aparte de eso tu funcion sumar no esta haciendo ningun return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que en alguna parte que no mostraste estás definiendo `arrayinput`, de lo contrario, no podrías enviarlo por AJAX, porque en la función `guardar()` no recibes parámetros, entonces, ahí mismo define `sumaT`:

```
// Definir en contexto global, fuera de funciones
let arrayInput = [];
let sumaT = 0;
```

Entonces, en el resto de funciones no es necesario que recibas el arreglo como parámetro, por ejemplo:

```
// No es necesario el parámetro, porque es variable global
function sumar(arrayinput) { ... }
```

La función completa quedaría:

```
function sumar() {
    var listaT = document.querySelector('#listaT');
    listaT.innerHTML = '';
    let suma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
        suma += arrayinput[i];
    }
    var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
    listaT.appendChild(listaLi);
    listaLi.innerText = suma;
    console.log("suma total", suma);

    // Actualizas la variable global
    sumaT = suma;
}
```

### Actualización:

Tienes dos funciones para guardar, en una envías solo el arreglo y en la otra solo la suma, sin embargo, en PHP intentas obtener ambos.

Solución: Una sola función para enviar los dos datos:

```
function guardar() {
    var lista = { "data": arrayinput };
    var json = JSON.stringify(lista);
    ajax("procesos/Procesoventa.php", { "array": json, "suma": sumaT })
    .done(function(info) {
        console.log(info);
    });
}
```

Con esos pequeños cambios ya no debes tener problema para recibir la variable en PHP:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['array'], true);
$suma = $_POST['suma'];
var_dump($array);
var_dump($suma);
```

Comment: el array ya lo tengo echo y lo recibo bien en php solo me queda la suma por eso no puse nada sobre el array

Comment: ¿Revisaste que funciona? Lo del arreglo lo mencione porque sí te funciona y para que sepas porqué eso sí y la suma no.

Comment: me sigue dando null

Comment: En PHP obtienes la suma así: `$suma = $_POST['suma'];` porque es una variable simple y no un objeto.

Comment: mmm me sale lo mismo a lo mejor lo estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Edita la pregunta para mostrar tu código _Javascript_ actual, incluyendo donde defines las variables.

Comment: las estoy definiendo hasta arriba de mi archivo js pero me sigue saliendo null

Comment: Sin ver tu código actualizado va a ser difícil encontrar el error.

Comment: pues ya puse todo el codigo js que tengo

Comment: Veo dos errores, uno mío: al inicio debe ser `let sumaT = 0;` y el otro tuyo: No estás agregando `sumaT = suma;` al final de la función `sumar()`

Comment: sigue dando null ya lo actualice asi como tengo el codigo ahorita

Comment: Revisa la actualización

Comment: mmmm ya, intentare

Comment: mmm no sigue dando null  parte de que me sale indefinido

Comment: ya gracias, disculpa por dar mucha lata

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu problema está del lado del cliente.

Suponiendo que la `suma = 3432`, al usar la [función json.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) tendrías un resultado igual a

`"{"data":3432}"`

Por lo tanto en tu función estás mandando el parámetro *data* de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    suma: "{"data":3432}"
}
```

Dicho de otro modo, las variables sumaT y jsonsuma están sobrando y la forma de montar tu requisición

```
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST", // Importante indicar el método HTTP a usar para la requisición.
      url: "procesos/Procesototal.php",
      data: { suma: suma } //Pasa el valor directo que obtuviste de la suma
    }).done(function(info) {
        console.log(info);
    });
```

Puede ver la documentación completa de la función AJAX en este [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: intentare gracias

Comment: Perfecto, espero que te sirva la respuesta y ahí marcas como "mejor respuesta" junto con un voto positivo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @CesarUrdaneta el término adecuado es **respuesta aceptada**